# Installing Oracle Developer Tools for VS2013

Tags: oracle, odp.net, visual-studio-2013

The installer for the latest version of Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio only has options for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 - does anyone know a way to add 2013 to the list?  I cannot use VS2013 until I can get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODT is not available yet for VS2013. The current latest release (ODT 12.1.0.1.0) only supports 2008, 2010 and 2012.

Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html

"Integration with Visual Studio: Use Server Explorer with Visual Studio 2012 to browse your Oracle schema and launch one of the many integrated Oracle designers and wizards to create and alter schema objects. Use Microsoft Query Designer to visually design queries. Visual Studio 2010 and 2008 are also supported."

Comment: It is now supported as of ODT 12.1.0.1.2 or later. You can download it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Answer (score 6):

As of ODT Version 12.1.0.1.2 Visual Studio 2013 is supported:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/newfeatures-084113.html

The Oracle provider is not yet currently built against EF6 so if you are planning on using Entity Framework in MVC5, you need to install EF5 by running "Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0" on the Package Manager Console.

If you are starting a bootstrapped MVC5 WebApp don't use the Individual User Account membership provider as it relies on EF6. You can go for one of the many alternate membership providers (http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/membership)

Comment: You need ODT 12.1.0.1.2 or later and you can download it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html